How to make Illuminate\View\Component class to work with wire:click= methods?
In laravel 11 / livewire 3 app I have a component(Illuminate\View\Component) which shows
listing of QuizCategory models :
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\Common;

use App\Enums\ConfigValueEnum;
use App\Models\QuizCategory;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class CardItemsListing extends Component
{
    public string $listingTitle = 'You can pass one of our quizzes';
    ...
    public function __construct(?string $listingTitle = null, ?string $locale = '', ?int $quizCategoryId = null, ?int $page = 1)
    {
        $this->listingTitle = $listingTitle;
    }

    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        ...
        $quizCategories = QuizCategory::query()
            ->getByActive(true)
            ->withCount('quizzes')
            ->paginate();

        return view('components.common.card-items-listing', [
            'navListing' => $quizCategories->toArray(),
            'quizCategories' => $quizCategories
        ]);
    }
}

and in blade file I show $quizCategories array ok.
Now  I need do add some actions in components.common.card-items-listing blade file , like :
<div class="flex flex-grow pl-2">
        <img src="/img/favorite.png" alt="Save in Favorites" wire:click="SaveInFavorites( '{{$quizCategory['id']}}' )"/>
    </div>

    <div class="w-16  align-items-end justify-end align-top m-0 p-1 d2">
        <img src="/img/disable.png" alt="Disable this quiz" wire:click="disableQuiz( '{{ $quizCategory['id'] }}' )" />
    </div>

I suppose that wire:click= will not work with Illuminate\View\Component component.
a) Have I to remade it to Livewire\Component class?
b) Can I refer with these actions to common laravel controller ?
c) In some other way ?

a) Have I to remade it to Livewire\Component class?
Just change the import of Component class to "Livewire\Component", move your blade file into livewire folder and use this component inside of other blade file.
b) Can I refer with these actions to common laravel controller?
You can create action classes and than create proxy methods for these classes.
This is an example of action.
public function disableQuiz(int $quizId, DisableQuizAction $disableQuizAction): void // use DI to get action class
{
    // maybe some authorization...

    $disableQuizAction->run($quizId);
}

If this method should mutate a state of multiple values, consider using Livewire Forms and pass form to action.

no this way does not work. looks like need to recreate a new component with php artisan command
